# Wrong UICollectionViewCell size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to change size of my UICollectionViewCell

In Interface Builder I set custom size

[image]

In my code I want change size of cell

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(274, 274);
}
```

In future I need have different size of cell

In my cell I have next method

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    backImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.width, self.height / 1.32)];
    [self addSubview:backImageView];
    lineImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, backImageView.height, self.width, self.height / 9.67)];
    [self addSubview:lineImageView];
    nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(28, lineImageView.originY + 5, self.width - 28, 15)];
    nameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:FontStyleBold size:14];
    [self addSubview:nameLabel];
    descriptLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(nameLabel.originX, lineImageView.originY + lineImageView.height + 3, nameLabel.width - nameLabel.originX, 25)];
    descriptLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    descriptLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:FontStyle size:8];
    [self addSubview:descriptLabel];
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    self.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(-1, 2.0, self.width + 2, self.height + 2) cornerRadius:0.f].CGPath;
    self.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = .4f;
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0f;
}
```

In simulator I have next bad result

[image]

If I set in Interface Builder size

[image]

In simulator all good

[image]

I thought that next method must change size of cell, but it change size of item

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(274, 274);
}
```

So how can I change size of UICollectionViewCell programmatically, without help of Interface Builder?

Comment: If you delete the values in IB it usually helps :)

Comment: If I delete, IB automatically set 0,0 and problem remain

Answer (score 0):

Is your view controller a `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`? 
Otherwise `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` won't get called.
Maybe insert an `NSLog` inside `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` to see if it gets called at all.

Answer (score 0):

I find my mistake.
In `awakeFromNib` I set height of subviews but in

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout  
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

forgot update frames of subviews

Comment: maybe you can mark your answer as the questions answer so the post is marked as solved.